# How can I completely remove rbenv, rvm, ruby, and rails from my system?

Tags: ubuntu, rvm, rbenv

I want to completely remove rbenv, rvm, Ruby, and Rails from my system so I can install rbenv and Ruby from a clean slate. I have tried to use `sudo apt remove`, `sudo apt purge`, `sudo apt autoremove`, and `sudo apt uninstall` for both rbenv and rvm and I've removed the `~/.rvm` and `~/.rbenv` folders, yet both still seem to be installed on my machine. I restarted the terminal after each attempt. I would like both version managers, all gems, and all versions of Ruby to be completely purged from the system with no trace left behind. What is the proper way to go about doing this?

#### Update:

I've managed to remove rbenv by repeating all the previous steps I had tried before, however, now when trying to remove rvm, I get the following error:

```
dpkg: rvm: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 ruby-full depends on ruby; however:
  Package ruby is not configured yet.
  Package rvm which provides ruby is to be removed.
 rake depends on ruby | ruby-interpreter; however:
  Package ruby is not configured yet.
  Package rvm which provides ruby is to be removed.
  Package ruby-interpreter is not installed.
 ruby-test-unit depends on ruby | ruby-interpreter; however:
  Package ruby is not configured yet.
  Package rvm which provides ruby is to be removed.
  Package ruby-interpreter is not installed.

(Reading database ... 344123 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing rvm (1.29.3-1) ...
groupdel: cannot remove the primary group of user 'josh'
dpkg: error processing package rvm (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 8
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rvm
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying they **seem to be installed on my machine**?

Comment: `apt list --installed | grep rvm` returns `rvm/now 1.29.3-1 all [installed,local]` and `$ rbenv --version` returns `rbenv 1.1.1-37-g1c772d5`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this thanks to an answer I found here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/438345/how-to-remove-install-a-package-that-is-not-fully-installed/632523

If someone would like to mark this as a duplicate or something.